# mini Christmas lights

Tags: voltage

I have a string of 20 mini Christmas lights (not LED) and I would like to reduce the string of 20 to a string of 2.  Can I put a resistor(s) in the string to avoid the bulbs burning out?

Comment: Use 12V + R......

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can - but a simplistic attempt will lead you astray.
Other advice given so far may mislead (and/or kill) you.

ALL these questions are important:

- Does it use a low voltage power supply?
  Some don't!!!
  **If it is direct mains connected - as some such are - then it can easily kill you.**
- Can you supply a well focused photo of the light string and of the power supply spec plate (if it has one).
- If it has a power supply, do you know the power supply voltage?
  Is it AC or DC ?
  (Both should be on the power supply).
- How many wires from the string to the power input? 
  MAY be 2. May be more.
- What is your mains voltage

**If it is direct mains plug in you can still do what you want but need to take exceptional care.**

Using AC or DC range to suit supply, using an appropriate range use a DMM (digital multimeter) or similar to measure the voltage across the entire operating string.
Result = ?

Using AC or DC range to suit supply, using an appropriate range use a DMM (digital multimeter) or similar to measure the voltage across a single operating bulb.
Result = ?

If Vbulb ~= Vstring / 20 then they are in series.

If direct mains connected Vbulb is
= 110/20 ~~= 5.5VAc or
230 VAC/20 ~~= 11 VAC

Set DMM to AC or DC current range.
Insert DMM in series with whole string.
DO NOT KILL YOURSELF :-( :-)
Measure string current.
Result = ?

---

Here is what you need to do for the worst case - and most likely - direct mains connection.
If your string is not connected this way, provide the test results connected and I/we will advise further.

**If bulbs are in series and mains powered directly.**

Rseries = V/I = Vstring_measured (in volts) / I string measured (in AMPS)

eg if Vstraing = 110 VAC, and I string = 150 mA **= 0.15 AMP**
Rseries = 110/0.15 =~ 33,000 Ohms.

Ideally use 2 resistors of half the value each in series. This redcues the voltage across each - some resistors are NOT rated for mains voltage use, regardless of power

Resistor power rating = Vmeasured x I measured x 2
In this example = 110 x 0.15 x 2 = 33 Watts.
That is a larger value than you'd hope - but 3 x 10,000 Ohm x 10 Watt resistors in series will do the job.

Note I have replaced effectively 20 bulbs - not just 18 - this will run the string VERY SLIGHTLY lower in output than before. You will not notice the difference.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a parallel string of lamps, you can just chop the end of and insulate the cut wires. the shorter string will just work.

But strings are series strings. The series string of 2 bulbs wants a voltage \$1\over10\$ of the string of 20 (because 20 is \$10\times 2\$). So if your wall outlet puts out a voltage in the region of 120V, you can use a 12V supply to run it. the bulbs don't mind if the supply is AC or DC, so if you have the adaptor plug from an old internet router (or similar 12V DC supply) you can use that.

If your wall outlet is more like 240V you've got a problem, but in this case that can be solved by connecting the bulbs in parallel, and the the 12V supply will again work (because in this setup the two want 24 when in series so each bulb wants 12V)

Comment: Thank you, this did it.  I had an old 12V power supply (I save all kinds of those things) and I wired it on to a string of two lamps and it works.  I appreciate your advice.

Answer (score -3):

You sure can. Try a range of resistor values and see how they affect the brightness of your lights.

Also, you can try this...
Cut off the 18 lights and measure across them, what resistance do you read?
Use a resistor that measures the same amount of ohms as your 18 lights.

Comment: If they just measure the resistance cold, then I would probably recommend starting off with a resistor with 2x the resistance of the 18 lights.  Hot incandescent bulbs have higher resistance than cold. .  Also I would make sure the resistor is rated for the wattage it will dissipate.  It might get toasty.

Comment: If by "not LED" he means incandescent, then ... no.  The cold and hot resistances will be significantly different, with the cold resistance being much lower than the bulbs' resistance when operating.

Comment: If you add the info I commented on and comment on how he might estimate the power usage of the resistor I'll give you an upvote.

Comment: **This answer is dangerously inadequate**.

Comment: Doesn't work. Incandescents that are not on have a very different resistance than incandescents that are on.

Comment: @CarlMeisel  don't. this is a dangerous answer.